# How to understand (void*)0

Tags: macros, null

Recently in my exercise I have found a question (void*)0 answered NULL pointer how to understand this actually.

How can this be understood? 
Is this is what the definition of macro NULL?

Comment: Please provide us a code snippet. I'm not really an expert, but I even don't understand what language you are using oO

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually ((void *)0) is a correct definition of the NULL pointer.